# Deleting multiple nodes from XML with XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I have XML that looks something like that:

```
<1>
    <2>
        <3>
        <3>
        <3>
    </2>
    <2>
        <3>
        <3>
    </2>
</1>
```

I need to always have only one '3' element in each '2' so I need to delete additional ones with XQuery.

I'm looping through 2's and then 3's but Im not very experienced with XQuery to be able to condition it to only delete those addidional nodes.

Comment: While asking an XQuery question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XQuery that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XQuery processor and its conformance with the XQuery standards: 1.0, 3.0, 3.1, or 4.0.

Comment: Additionally, XML element names must begin with letters. XML element names may contain digits, however they may not begin with them.

Answer (score 2):

I had to fix your XML to make it legit.

Tested in BaseX 10.4.

**XQuery**

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare context item := document {
<root>
    <level2>
        <level3/>
        <level3/>
        <level3/>
    </level2>
    <level2>
        <level3/>
        <level3/>
    </level2>
</root>
};

copy $input := .
modify delete node $input/root/level2/level3[position() gt 1]
return $input
```

**Output**

```
<root>
  <level2>
    <level3/>
  </level2>
  <level2>
    <level3/>
  </level2>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XQuery update facility (XQUF) as Yitzhak Khabinsky showed.

Another option is to recursively traverse the element-tree.

```xml
xquery version "3.0";

declare variable $xml :=
<root>
    <level2>
        <level3/>
        <level3/>
        <level3/>
    </level2>
    <level2>
        <level3/>
        <level3/>
    </level2>
</root>

declare function local:traverse-and-keep-first-level3($n as element()+) {
  if (count($n[. instance of element(level3)]) > 1)
  then $n[1]
  else $n ! (element { node-name(.) } {
    local:traverse-and-keep-first-level3(./element())
  })
};

local:traverse-and-keep-first-level3($xml/element())
```

Live code: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDbxmf